# Download of xls working in IE/Firefox but named as aspx page in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, download

I'm having an issue with Chrome renaming an export file to the default of the page name where the export is being initiated from.  I've gone through all related forum posts I could find and have tried all suggestions - I'm not seeing any recent posts within the past couple of years.

My code for the export (before any modification attempts) is as follows:

```
public static void ExportToSpreadsheet(object items, string name)
{
    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.Clear();
    response.ClearHeaders();
    response.Charset = "";
    response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    response.AddHeader("Context-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + name + "\"");

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid dg = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataGrid();
            dg.DataSource = items;
            dg.DataBind();
            dg.RenderControl(htw);
            response.Write(sw.ToString());
            response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

The above code works flawlessly in IE/Firefox.  The resulting result headers received (per Chrome net-internals) is:

```
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Context-Disposition: attachment;filename="DataExport.xls"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcTXlfRGF0YVxBVFNNXERldjQwXHBvcnRhbFxDR0lfQXV0b21hdGlvbl9GcmFtZXdvcmtcQXV0b21hdGlvbl9EZWNrLmFzcHg=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 19:37:05 GMT
Content-Length: 86493
```

I've tried several updates that includes hard coding the filename to "test.xls", clearing content of the response, setting buffer to true, setting CacheControl and Pragma to no-cache, and overriding VerifyRenderingInServerForm() in the page's code-behind. The response headers after applying all these changes are as follows:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Context-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xls"
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcTXlfRGF0YVxBVFNNXERldjQwXHBvcnRhbFxDR0lfQXV0b21hdGlvbl9GcmFtZXdvcmtcQXV0b21hdGlvbl9EZWNrLmFzcHg=?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 05 Dec 2014 19:10:23 GMT
Content-Length: 86493
```

This still produces the same results where Chrome is not recognizing/accepting the filename and defaults back to the pagename as the downloaded filename.

Any recommendations for how to fix this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Chrome Version 39.0.2171.71 m

Comment: Side note, you're not actually writing a .xls file to the client. You're writing HTML but giving it an Excel file extension. Excel will complain about that, which can be confusing to users. If the Open Office XML Spreadsheet format/Excel 2007/.xlsx format is okay, I'd highly reccomend switching to a library that can natively generate that format such as [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/), [NPOI](https://npoi.codeplex.com/), or [Open Office XML SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854%28v=office.15%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, you are correct that this is a poor man's export of html table data.  Thank you for clarifying that, mason.